# Searching via useTextEditingController of RIverpod not working

Tags: search, riverpod

I have a textfield with controller supplied via useTextEditingController. The controller text is supposed to be a value passed to a function in a provider controller to search corresponding products and display same. However, no search results are being returned. I have confirmed via a print() statement that the value read and supposedly passed is what the user entered into the textfield. I am at my wits end as to why the results (proList) are not being returned to the callBack for display. Here are the relevant code snippets.

Please note that I took care of case sensitivity by converting search text to lowercase before query to ensure that doesn't affect the query.  Thanks for your help or pointers.

search_screen.dart

```
class SearchScreen extends HookConsumerWidget {
  static const routeName = '/searchScreen';
  SearchScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  late List<Product> _searchList = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    List<Product> prodSearchList =
        ref.watch(productControllerProvider.notifier).products;

    final _searchTextController = useTextEditingController();
    final FocusNode _node = FocusNode();
    final _isSearchFieldEmpty = useState<bool>(true);
    bool isSearchFieldEmpty() {
      return _searchTextController.text.isEmpty;
    }

    useEffect(() {
      _searchTextController.addListener(() {
        _isSearchFieldEmpty.value = isSearchFieldEmpty();
      });
    }, [_searchTextController]);

    return Scaffold(
      bottomSheet: TextField(
        autofocus: true,
        controller: _searchTextController,
        focusNode: _node,
        decoration: kTextInputDecoration.copyWith(
          hintText: 'Item name here ...',
          filled: true,
          fillColor: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
          prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.search),
          suffixIcon: IconButton(
            onPressed: _searchTextController.text.isEmpty
                ? null
                : () {
                    _searchTextController.clear();
                  },
            icon: Icon(Icons.close,
                color: _searchTextController.text.isNotEmpty
                    ? Colors.red
                    : Colors.grey),
          ),
        ),
        onChanged: (val) {
          _searchList =
              ref.watch(productControllerProvider.notifier).getBySearch(val);
        },
      ),
      body: _searchTextController.text.isNotEmpty && _searchList.isEmpty
          ? Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: const [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 50,
                  ),
                  Icon(
                    Icons.search,
                    size: 50,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 60,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Sorry no results found.',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          : Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: GridView.builder(
                gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                  childAspectRatio: 2 / 3,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                ),
                itemCount: prodSearchList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                  if (_searchTextController.text.isNotEmpty) {
                    return FeedsProduct(
                      id: _searchList[i].id,
                      description: _searchList[i].description,
                      imageUrl: _searchList[i].imageUrl,
                      isFavorite: _searchList[i].isFavorite,
                      price: _searchList[i].price,
                      quantity: _searchList[i].quantity,
                    );
                  } else {
                    return FeedsProduct(
                      id: prodSearchList[i].id,
                      description: prodSearchList[i].description,
                      imageUrl: prodSearchList[i].imageUrl,
                      isFavorite: prodSearchList[i].isFavorite,
                      price: prodSearchList[i].price,
                      quantity: prodSearchList[i].quantity,
                    );
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

product_controller.dart:

```
final productControllerProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider<ProductListController>(
  (ref) => ProductListController(),
);

class ProductListController extends ChangeNotifier {
  // ProductListController([List<Product>? state]) : super();

  List<Product> get products => _products;

  List<Product> getByCatName(String catName) {
    List<Product> catList = _products
        .where(
            (e) => e.productCategoryName.toLowerCase() == catName.toLowerCase())
        .toList();
    return catList;
  }

  List<Product> getByBrandName(String brandName) {
    List<Product> brandList = _products
        .where((e) => e.brand.toLowerCase() == brandName.toLowerCase())
        .toList();
    return brandList;
  }

  List<Product> get popularProducts {
    return _products.where((e) => e.isPopular).toList();
  }

  Product getById(String prodId) {
    return _products.firstWhere((e) => e.id == prodId);
  }

  List<Product> getBySearch(String query) {
    List<Product> prodSearchResult = _products
        .where(
          (e) => e.title.toLowerCase() == query.toLowerCase(),
        )
        .toList();
notifyListeners();
    return prodSearchResult;
  }
```

[image: Search screen displaying all products before search]
[image: Screen after entering item name of apple (an item that exists but not returned as you can see]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to create _searchList as a HookState instead of a late in your class.

```
 final _searchList = useState<List<Product>>([]);
 
 onChanged: (val) {
   _searchList.value = ref.watch(productControllerProvider.notifier).getBySearch(val);
 },
```

Also you have your search method wrong, you don't actually have an `Apple` product, you have an `Apple MacBookAir ...` so your equal `e.title.toLowerCase() == query.toLowerCase()` will never be true, if you really want to search ignoring case and containing words you need to use RegExp

```
List<Product> getBySearch(String query) {
  final RegExp regex = RegExp(query, caseSensitive: false);
  List<Product> prodSearchResult = _products
    .where((e) => e.title.contains(regex))
    .toList();
  notifyListeners();
  return prodSearchResult;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million partner. I was so blind to capturing the difference between contains and exact match using ==. Moreover, I like your implementation using regex and useState(). Everything works as expected.